# Formulation of the U-matrix (unified distance matrix) as a matrix operation?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matrix, som

I am computing the u-matrix in parallel, and am concerned with the computational cost of traversing matrices in Python, as opposed to computing values by means of matrix operations using Numpy.

When computing the u-matrix, you need the distance to the nearest nodes, the neighborhood.  It seems hard to find that out without actually picking them out with a for loop.

To make a simple example, in a 2-d grid you want the neighborhood for the node with coordinates [u,v]: [[u-v,v], [u+1,v], [u,v-1], [u,v+1]].

Is there away you for example extract a neighborhood with a Numpy?  Then I know how I can compute the euclidean distance for all such points.  Or otherwise reformulate the problem?

What would happen to the u-matrix if the distance from each node to all other nodes in the grid as opposed to the nearest n?

Comment: Have you looked at the distance module of scipy? There might be something there already doing what you need, for example pdist. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.distance.html

Comment: How exactly are your arrays that describe the positions of the nodes in feature space currently laid out?

Comment: Thanks to the comment of @M4rtini above here, I did it by iterating through all coordinates in the matrix, and then computing pairwise distances to a specific neighborhood for each of them, and then doing the summing and normalization on this.  The matrices are 3-dimensional with the dimensionality of the node vectors as the third.  For sorting colors this would be 3.